# R and sf - How to know this exists, data(us_states), without first using, (requireNamespace("sf", quietly = TRUE))

Tags: r, sf

I am not new to using R, but I am newer to using the sf package, or any other similar geospatial packages.

I can easily explore and subset the world dataset and then plot the map of the US -  which includes Alaska and Hawaii. This data is easily explored from the top down using the pipe tool and subsetting.  But I actually only want to plot the map of the continental US.  Using the tools I normally use, I am unable to find an easy way of creating this plot.

A web search returned this website and showed the following code used to create the plot with the wanted feature:

```
if (requireNamespace("sf", quietly = TRUE)) {
  library(sf)
  data(us_states)

  plot(us_states["REGION"])
}

states49 <- (us_states["NAME"])
states49
```

What is this?  I've been using R for sometime and have never come across any code similar to this before.  I've never seen or used requireNamespace before. I never even knew this function existed.   As I mentioned earlier, it's easy to subset into the us_states using those tools I commonly use.

Using my regular tools, I never knew this data existed.  I would never have found this data without having used the code sample found from this website. Even the R official documentation says, "It's rare to load a package explicitly, but it can be done with:

```
requireNamespace()
loadNamespace() "
```

Link to quoted R documentation: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html

So, to the point, how is someone supposed to know this data exists, when it might exist, when it doesn't exist, etc..  When would I suspect data like this might exist?  And when to find such data when such data might or might not exist?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  Google lead you to what website?  Please [edit] your question and include a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackExchange Gray,

I can see some understandable confusion.

`us_states` is a data object in the `spData` package. So to use it (after you've installed `spData`) all you need is :

```
library(spData)
library(sf)
plot(us_states["REGION"])
```

(#data(us_states) # is not usually needed because most package data are lazyLoaded i.e. auto loaded when needed)

This will show you what data are in the package :

```
data(package='spData')
```

You don't need `requireNameSpace()` it is used in that code snippet to check whether the sf package - which is needed for the plotting is installed.

Note that I didn't see the link to the data in your original question on my first read and I wasn't aware of 'us_states', so to find out about it I googled 'us_states sf' and it found the spData page.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I found some information that partially answers my question. This data is clearly bundled with the sf package.

But my central question remains: How is someone supposed to even know this information exists?  This information is not discovered during a typical top-down review of the world dataset.

link to the the data shown below:
https://nowosad.github.io/spData/reference/us_states.html

Source: R/us_states.R

The object loaded is a sf object containing the contiguous United States data from the US Census Bureau with a few variables from American Community Survey (ACS)

us_states

Format

Formal class 'sf' [package "sf"]; the data contains a data.frame with 49 obs. of 7 variables:

GEOID character vector of geographic identifiers

NAME character vector of state names

REGION character vector of region names

AREA area in square kilometers of units class

total_pop_10 numerical vector of total population in 2010

total_pop_15 numerical vector of total population in 2015

geometry sfc_MULTIPOLYGON

The object is in geographical coordinates using the NAD83 datum.

NAME character vector of state names

REGION character vector of region names

AREA area in square kilometers of units class

total_pop_10 numerical vector of total population in 2010

total_pop_15 numerical vector of total population in 2015

geometry sfc_MULTIPOLYGON

The object is in geographical coordinates using the NAD83 datum.

Source
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html

See also
See the tigris package: https://cran.r-project.org/package=tigris

Examples

```
if (requireNamespace("sf", quietly = TRUE)) {
  library(sf)
  data(us_states)

  plot(us_states["REGION"])
}
```